# @RequestParam How to handle incorrectly framed URLs

Tags: spring-mvc

I am having a method test like below and making a RESTful webservice call to fetch the data,

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/select", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(
@RequestParam(value="begin", defaultValue="0",required=false) final String begin
)
{
//Some java code
}

**RESTful Webservice Call:**
http://localhost:8081/a/b/c/select?begin=1
Returning the data properly

http://localhost:8081/a/b/c/select?begin:1
Here in the url = has been replaced with : for negative testing.
Here Spring ignores the given value 1 and picks the default value 0 and returns the data accordingly without errors

Question:
But I want to capture the actual URL field with value which is begin:1, do some validation and display error message that the url is incorrect.

I understood that begin:1 is not considered as part of url by spring and hence picks the default value. Wondering is there a way in Spring to capture the wrongly framed url's.
Any pointers would be helpful. Many Thanks!
```

Comment: So do you have a restful service that you are not providing client libraries for? There are a few things you need to consider about your api development one of which is HATEOS or Hypermedia. Should your clients be creating their own URLs? BTW, there is a "default value" that you can set for request params. You could look to see if it is using that default value and return them back an error message if it is the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Clients would be using the URL given by us. http://localhost:8081/a/b/c/select? would be the base url and there are many other parameters similar to begin=1.                        
'begin' is assigned with a default value 0 and 'required=false'. 
I cannot do a check for default value and return a error msg because in some cases the scenario is valid. 
The user can even shoot the url http://localhost:8081/a/b/c/select?end=1 , here begin will be default to 0.

Comment: Yeah, you need to look deeper into HATEOS and building the URL incrementally. If that case is valid but only in certain contexts you need to direct them to those contexts.